# Unable to upload to Azure storage

Tags: ios, swift

I have a piece of code

```
let account = try AZSCloudStorageAccount(fromConnectionString: connectionString)
let blobClient = account.getBlobClient()
let blobContainer = blobClient.containerReference(fromName: containerName)

let currentDate = Date()
let fileName = String(currentDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)+".json"
let blob = blobContainer.blockBlobReference(fromName: fileName)

var blobArray = [String]()
blobArray.append("String Value")
blob.upload(from: blobArray, completionHandler: {(error)->Void in
    print("Test uploaded!")
})
```

That I am trying to use to get an array (JSON) uploaded to Azure storage. I realise the array is not valid JSON but I am just trying to get the upload working first.

The issue I get is

```
Unable to infer closure type in the current context
```

but I don't know how to resolve it. I have been searching for the last hour trying to find information but nothings worked.

Comment: what type(s) does Azure's `upload` take?  I know it takes `NSData` and possibly `NSArray`, but your `blobArray` is a native Swift array.  Maybe try to convert it to a `NSArray` and see what happens.

Comment: Converting it to var blobArray = Array<String>() didn't change anything. Still getting Unable to infer closure type error.

Comment: `Array<String>` isn't the same thing as `NSArray`.  Try `let blobNSArray = NSArray(array: blobArray)` and pass that into your `blob.upload`.